# whats a good ios charting library/framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, charts, core-plot

Has anyone got any recommendations for a charting library/framework for ios. I need to be able to create bar, pie, line trend, scatter charts from an internal database/warehouse onto an iPad. I've read some mixed reports about core-plot.

Comment: Core Plot is pretty well-known and well-supported. It's used in plenty of apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've used this in the past
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

and found it to be the most reliable!

Answer (score 17):

iOS chart libraries

**1.Core Plot :**   https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Core Plot is a plotting framework for OS X and iOS. It provides 2D visualisation of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.

*Advantage:*
Core Plot is a free, open source charting library available under the New BSD License.

Example Graphs :
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Example-Graphs#wiki-dropplot-example-app

**2.Shinobi Charts :**  http://www.shinobicontrols.com/ios/shinobicharts

Shinobi Controls released their new charting library, Shinobi Charts. This is a paid library but with a free 30 day trial available. It features several chart types, from Pie and Donut to Bar and Column and Area charts.Shinobi comes packaged with a comprehensive set of apple style documentation.

*Advantage:*

In terms of the smoothness of the interaction with the charts, Shinobi has a clear advantage. Pan and zoom have momentum and smoothly move to the new range requested. The performance of the Shinobi interaction is also markedly better than Core Plot, especially when there are a lot of labels visible on the chart.

Shinobi is very lightweight and perfect.

Price plans :
http://www.shinobicontrols.com/ios/shinobicharts/price-plans

**3.KeepEdge  :**  http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/

The KeepEdge iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C is a paid library with a free trial available. It features a wide range of chart types, ranging from a standard line chart to Stock High Low charts and 3D Clustered Bar charts. KeepEdge does include a TimeSeries chart, with a date/time axis.

*Price plans* :
http://www.keepedge.com/purchase/#pIphoneChart

**4.JBChartView :**  https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView

Jawbone's iOS-based charting library for both line and bar graphs. It is easy to set-up, and highly customizable.

*Features :*

1. Drop-in UIView subclass supported across all devices.
2. Lie and bar graph support.
3. Simple to use protocols modeled after a UITableView.
4. Highly customizable.
5. Expand & collapse animation support.

*Disadvantage :*

1. Requires iOS 7 or later.
2. Requires Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

   After a bit of googling , i have found that **Core-plot** is one of most flexible libraries and free of cost . But if we can afford paid one **ShinobiControls** is worth of buying , it provides  iOS software and Android components to ease the development of native, cross platform mobile apps.

**Update**

**5. SwiftCharts :** https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts

This is a new charts library for iOS, written in Swift. It's free, open source, said to be easy to use and highly customizable. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyAlKil3Pyk).

**6. SciChart :** https://www.scichart.com/ios-charts

This is a new chart library for iOS, written in Objective-C and supporting Swift as well. It's paid, but very powerful for streaming charts and realtime updates. [Video](https://youtu.be/rfJsWVm4Epc).

Comment: I really love this kind of answers.

Comment: time to add ios-charts?

Comment: A friend of mine developed a good one MIMCharts : https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library

Answer (score 0):

Coreplot is good for an open source option, but struggles with large data sets.

We've developed a suite of speedy iOS controls. We're launching charts soon, there's free trials, if you're interested?

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just released a new CocoaPod called [CHRadarGraph](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CHRadarGraph).  It's a circular bar graph that allows dense amount of data to be viewed in a smaller space.

[Take a look!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uCmL.png)

Comment: it may be you can add examples of usage, more information, so your answer could be counted [a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)? thank you